# When to use addressof(x) instead of &x?

Tags: c++, addressof

How do I decide whether I need `addressof(x)` instead of `&x` when taking the address of an object?

---

Seems like the question was confusing, so a clarification is in order:

`addressof` obviously bypasses the overloaded address-of operator. **I'm already aware of that.**

What I want to know is:
**How do I know if that's what I really want to do? (Especially when inside a template, etc.)**

Is there some kind of "rule" that helps me figure out when I need `addressof` instead of `&`?
After all, they both return the "address of" the object, so when do I use which?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You use `std::addressof` when you have to. Sadly, "when you have to" includes anytime you are working in template code and want to turn a variable of unknown type `T` or `T&` into an honest-to-God pointer to that variable's memory.

Because the C++ committee foolishly allowed the overloading of the reference operator (to little legitimate purpose), it is possible for a user to instantiate your template with some type that you can't use the reference operator to get an actual pointer to. `std::addressof` is a way to work around users who use this dubious C++ feature in order to do what the language should have guaranteed to work to begin with.

In short, it's a library fix for a language stupidity. Use it in template code instead of `&` if you want to make sure users can't break your code. If your users can be trusted not to use this ill-conceived feature, then you can use `&`.

Comment: What I find funny is that the *one* class I *expected* to overload address-of, `reference_wrapper`, doesn't seem to...

Comment: @Mehrdad: That doesn't surprise me; both `reference_wrapper` and `addressof` come from Boost. AKA: the people who most know the dangers of overloading that operator.

Comment: Looking back at this, I'm not sure if it was foolish to allow the address-of operator to be overloaded. It's useful for something like Boost.Lambda, to represent the action of taking an address. But it seems like it's just been misused.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I was surprised too. I think `reference_wrapper` is just a very thin layer of wrapper, one can devise a type that emulates a reference much better than `reference_wrapper`, including for example overloading `operator&`. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235818/type-emulating-a-c-reference-better-than-stdreference-wrapper  and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34144470/225186

Comment: @NicolBolas *"...  it is possible for a user to instantiate your template with some type that you can't use the reference operator to get an actual pointer to."* -- Would greatly appreciate it if you can edit your answer and add an example to elaborate on this sentence. I'm still confused. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Milan: As mentioned in the post, C++ allows overloading the prefix `&` operator. Such an overload may no longer return a pointer to the given object. So you have to use `std::addressof` to bypass that.

Answer (score 19):

If it's a user-defined type with overloaded unary `operator&`, and you want its address, use `addressof`.

I'd say you should always use `&` because, as you say, if you don't, it defeats the purpose of the overload. *Unless* of course you do something meaningful with the overload, in which case you'd need `addressof` (outside the class, inside you can just use `this`), but you have to be very certain of what you're doing.

Here's more - if you want to overload `operator&` outside the class (you can), you **have to** use `addressof` to return the address, otherwise it results in infinite recursion:

```
struct Class
{
   virtual ~Class() {}
   int x;
};

void* operator&(const Class& x)
{
    //return &x; <---- infinite recursion
    return addressof(x) + 4; //I know this isn't safe
                             //but I also know the intrinsics of my compiler
                             //and platform to know this will actually return
                             //the address to the first data member
}
```

**I know this isn't safe.**

Comment: Wouldn't it completely defeat the purpose of the overloaded operator though? How do I tell if I should defeat it or not?

Comment: Hmm, so this is a situation in which I *can't* even use `&` in the first place, which makes the question moot!

Comment: The infinite recursion problem can be solved simply by casting `x` to something else first: `return const_cast<char*>(&reinterpret_cast<const char&>(x))`.

Comment: @alecov Yes, because that's what the implementation of std::addressof actually does. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16195032/10732434).

Answer (score 11):

Use it when you want to know the actual address of the object, and not the result of an address-of `operator&` overload.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the operator overload?

Comment: @Mehrdad Maybe - but you get to choose whether you want the overload or not.

Comment: @Mehrdad If you trust everybody to implement nice `operator&`s.

Comment: @Mehrdad You use it when you need to know the actual address of the object, not the address it's `operator&` returns to you.

Comment: @juanchopanza: But the question is, how can I tell which situation I'm in? All your answer tells me is basically that you should "use `addressof` when you need it", which begs the question, when do I need it and when do I not? How do I tell?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Wait, `shared_ptr` has an overloaded `operator &`?

Comment: @Mehrdad no it doesn't, my bad!

Comment: @Mehrdad: "*Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the operator overload?*" You say that as thought there's *ever* a legitimate reason to overload that operator. `std::addressof` exists because the C++ standards committee screwed up.

Comment: @NicolBolas That would make a better answer than this and I would certainly up-vote it.

Answer (score 8):

My opinion only:

Unless you are part of the team designing the class and its interface, never.  I've personally never seen a good reason to overload that operator.  But if someone designs a class where it makes sense, and assuming the class is meant for public consumption(that is to say, the class is not for internal use only in a particular library), I will expect the class to work in normal code that naturally expects that `&` means "address of".  If the class that overloads the operator isn't designed in such a sensible way, then I wouldn't use that class, period.  Because either that class is broken, or it is not meant to be used outside the library which it is a part of.

Answer (score 7):

> After all, they both return the "address of" the object, so when do I use which?

You have absolutely no guarantee that an overloaded `operator&` is the "address of" the object, chances are it isn't, or the class author probably wouldn't have bothered to overload it.  They could have overloaded it to return a different type, or even to return `void` if they are ill-advisedly trying to prevent people taking its address.

If you want a pointer to an object which *might* have overloaded `&` (e.g. because its type is a template parameter so you don't know) then either use `std::addressof` or document that your template doesn't support types which don't return the object's real address as the right type.