# Implementation of addressof

Tags: c++, c++11

Having previously been unaware of the existence of `std::addressof`, why it exists makes sense to me: as a way of taking the an address in the presence of an overloaded `operator&`.  The implementation, however, is slightly more opaque. From `gcc 4.7.1`:

```
template<typename _Tp>
inline _Tp*
__addressof(_Tp& __r) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
{
  return reinterpret_cast<_Tp*>
(&const_cast<char&>(reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(__r)));
}
```

The `reinterpret_cast<_Tp*>` is obvious. The rest of it is dark magic. Can someone break down how this actually works?

Comment: Casting to `char&` (or `char *`) avoids breaking strict aliasing rules, and `operator&` cannot be overloaded for builtin types such as `char`. So you end up with a pointer to the base address of `_Tp`.

Comment: @Praetorian The aliasing rules aren't an issue here, since you don't dereference the results.  The reason `char` is used is that it cannot have alignment requirements; if you used `int`, and `int` had stricter alignment than `_Tp`, the conversion might change the actual address.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ahh, of course, didn't think about not reading from the cast result. Good thing I posted a comment instead of an answer :)

Comment: @JamesKanze: regarding "*[if] int had stricter alignment than _Tp, the conversion might change the actual address*" => wow I didn't realize C++ allows that, but then I'm not used to work with platforms having such strict alignment requirements. Thanks for the explanation, I didn't understand refp's remark about alignment at first!

Comment: @syam Using the results of the conversion (unless it is a character type) is undefined behavior, so the implementation can do anything it wants.  On byte addressed machines, `reinterpret_cast` conversions normally do nothing at the machine code level.  On word addressed machines, however, an `int*` will often be smaller than a `char*`; conversion of `char*` to `int*` will loose data.

Comment: @syam re "anything it wants": there is a requirement that if an address is converted to a type with doesn't have a stricter alignment requirement, and then back to the original type, the resulting pointer will compare equal to the original pointer.  But that's really it, in terms of what the standard required.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks again for the additional info. I admit I never bothered too much with the dark corners of `reinterpret_cast` since it is so easy to go UB, which is why I didn't realize the alignment / data loss issue until I saw your comment. That requirement explains clearly why it must be `char` since it is the only (or at least one of the very few) type that is guaranteed not to have a stricter alignment, and thus not to trigger UB. All makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

- First you have `__r` which is of type `_Tp&`
- It is `reinterpret_cast`'ed to a `char&` in order to ensure being able to later take its address without fearing an overloaded `operator&` in the original type; actually it is cast to `const volatile char&` because `reinterpret_cast` can always legally add `const` and `volatile` qualifiers even if they are not present, but it can't remove them if they are present (this ensures that whatever qualifiers `_Tp` had originally, they don't interfere with the cast).
- This is `const_cast`'ed to just `char&`, removing the qualifiers (legally now! `const_cast` can do what `reinterpret_cast` couldn't with respect to the qualifiers).
- The address is taken `&` (now we have a plain `char*`)
- It is `reinterpret_cast`'ed back to `_Tp*` (which includes the original `const` and `volatile` qualifiers if any).

**Edit:** since my answer has been accepted, I'll be thorough and add that the choice of `char` as an intermediate type is due to alignment issues in order to avoid triggering Undefined Behaviour. See @JamesKanze's comments (under the question) for a full explanation. Thanks James for explaining it so clearly.

Comment: Thanks. With this and the alignment fact brought up in other posts, it all makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: To confirm- no conversion operators can be applied during a `reinterpret_cast`, right?  They can only be applied during a `static_cast`?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Yes. static_cast, dynamic_cast and legacy C casts actually perform a conversion when needed, while reinterpret_cast and const_cast only change what type compiler *thinks* the data is, without ever converting the data itself.

Answer (score 14):

It's actually quite simple when you think about it, to get the real adress of an object/function in precense of an overloaded `operator&` you will need to treat the object as something other than what it really is, some type which cannot have an overloaded operator.. an *intrinsic type* (such as `char`).

A `char` has no alignment and can reside anywhere any other object can, with that said; casting an object to a reference to char is a very good start.

---

But what about the *black magic* involved when doing `reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>`?

In order to *reinterpret* the returned pointer from the implementation of `addressof` we will eventually want to discard qualifiers such as `const` and `volatile` (to end up with a plain reference `char`). These two can be added easily with `reinterpret_cast`, but asking it to remove them is illegal.

```
T1 const a; reinterpret_cast<T2&> (a);

/* error: reinterpret_cast from type ‘...’ to type ‘...’ casts away qualifiers */
```

<sup>It's a little bit of a *"better safe than sorry"* trick.. *"Let us add them, just in case, we will remove them later."*</sup>

---

Later we cast away the qualifiers (*const* and *volatile*) with `const_cast<char&>` to end up with a plain reference to `char`, this result is, as the final step, turned back into a pointer to whatever type we passed into our implementation.

A relevant question on this stage is why we didn't skip the use of `reinterpret_cast` and went directly to the `const_cast`? this too has a simple answer: *`const_cast` can add/remove qualifiers, but it cannot change the underlying type.*

```
T1 a; const_cast<T2&> (a);

/* error: invalid const_cast from type ‘T1*’ to type ‘T2*’ */
```

---

<sup>*it might not be easy as pie, but it sure tastes good when you get it..*</sup>

Answer (score 11):

**The short version:**

`operator&` can't be overloaded for `char`.  So the type is being cast to a `char` reference to get what's guaranteed to be the true address.

That conversion is done in two casts because of the restrictions on `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`.

**The longer version:**

It's performing three sequential casts.

```
reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>
```

This is effectively casting to a `char&`.  The `const` and `volatile` only exist because `_Tp` may be `const` or `volatile`, and `reinterpret_cast` can *add* those, but would be unable to *remove* them.

```
const_cast<char&>
```

Now the `const` and `volatile` have been removed.  `const_cast` may do that.

```
reinterpret_cast<_Tp*>(&result)
```

Now the address is taken and the type is converted back to a pointer to the original type.

Answer (score 6):

From inside out:

- First it casts `__r` type to a `const volatile char&`: It's casting to a `char&` just because it's a type that for sure doesn't have an overloaded `operator&` that does something funky. The `const volatile` is there because those are restrictions, they can be added but not taken away with `reinterpret_cast`. `_Tp` might've already been `const` and/or `volatile`, in which case one or both were needed in this cast. If it didn't, the cast just added them needlessly, but it is written for the most restrictive cast.
- Next, to take away the `const volatile` you need a `const_cast`, which leads to the next part... `const_cast<char&>`.
- From there they simply take the address and cast it to the type you want, a `_Tp*`. Note that `_Tp` might be `const` and/or `volatile`, which mean those things could be added back at this point.