# Why doesn't std::reference_wrapper implicitly cast to a reference when calling member function?

Tags: c++, reference, implicit-conversion

I don't understand exactly why one cannot use a `std::reference_wrapper` like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    void f() {};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> vrFoo;
    Foo foo;
    vrFoo.push_back(foo);
    // vrFoo[0].f(); // error
    vrFoo[0].get().f(); // or static_cast<Foo&>(v[0]).f();
}
```

Why do we have to use the `get()` member function? It looks like `std::reference_wrapper` has an implicit conversion to `T&` via `operator T&() const noexcept`, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper 
so why isn't `v[0]` implicitly converted to a reference?

In other situations, such as

```
std::cout << v[0] << std::endl
```

this conversion takes place (I assume here that `Foo` overloads `operator<<`)

Comment: It's a class member access. The member function is always looked up in the type of the LHS and no implicit conversions apply. The alternative (overloading `operator.`) is difficult to specify correctly; there has been numerous proposals over the years about it. The most recent one is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4173.pdf

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because `.` is always used to access members of the object it's applied to. Type conversions aren't considered.

There's a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4173.pdf) to allow overloading of `operator.`, to enable exactly what you want, but that won't be standard until at least C++17, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a language limitation as @MikeSeymour pointed out.

And this is the reason why I think `std::reference_wrapper` should have an overloaded `operator&` that returns the address of the wrapped object:

```
template<class T>
struct reference_wrapper{
   ...
   T* operator &(){return ptr;}
}
```

So that later one can use `&Foo->f()` or `(*&Foo).f()` instead of `Foo.get().f()` or `static_cast<T&>(Foo).f()`.

Comment: I think a problem here is that `operator*` _et al._ imply pointer semantics, i.e. '_Must I test this against`bool`/`nullptr`/`end` before deferencing?_', which is contrary to the (other, non-`<algorithm>`) purpose of `reference_wrapper` in such contexts: to obviate the questions & syntactical hoop-jumping posed by raw pointers. Although tedious & rather boilerplate, it's arguably still more readable to do as present: eschew `auto` to get 'deliberate implicit' conversion, declare an additional `Foo& foo = the_wrapper;` in other cases, etc. Anyway, `operator.` would be far superior if done right

Comment: @underscore_d, I am talking about `operator&`, not `operator*`. There is nothing to test for; `reference_wrapper` is always non-empty (it can be dangling, just as `T&` but that is another thing). The purpose for the current `reference_wrapper` is to be both a tag and transporter for reference. If it were implicitly convertible to `T&` you could at least apply any free function to the `reference_wrapper`, it is just a little step closer to `operator.`. About `auto` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888155/is-there-a-way-to-disable-auto-declaration-for-non-regular-types

Comment: So substitute the fact that you return a pointer, and I still think the semantics/statement of that are not correct for `reference_wrapper`. Next: `reference_wrapper` *is* implicitly convertible to `T&`, so I presume you meant something else, but I don't know what that is? Thanks for the link about `auto`; I vaguely recall noticing that before but forgot to read up on it. I guess that would be a good accompaniment for `operator.` too.

Comment: Yes, sorry I messed up. `reference_wrapper<T>` is implicitly convertible to `T&` (`operator T&`). What I mean is that for consistency it would be nice to have `operator&`, (and many other operators such as `operator[]`) while we wait for `operator.`. Note that `reference_wrapper` has an `operator()` already, why not all the others? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator()

Comment: I haven't pored over proposals, discussions, etc. but get a fairly clear impression that `reference_wrapper` was primarily to solve the problem of various stdlib algorithms copying functors, RNGs, etc. - & the use of it as a general-purpose non-owning reference type is more of a bonus than a motivation (albeit I think it's useful for that). So, to why it doesn't have all the other bells & whistles, I think the answer would be (a) that wasn't the main point of it and (b) there are proposals for far better and more thorough ways to handle such proxying, such as `operator.()`, `using auto=`, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d, sure, a real reference wrapper is a superset of `std::reference_wrapper`. The fact that `reference_wrapper` has a `operator()` (function call) shows it is got half way there.