# Does it make sense to specialize std::decay?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, std

I have class that represents an array reference (`class array_ref`) and another that *is* (i.e. holds/own/contains) the array (`class array`). 
`array_ref` behaves like a reference.

Does it make sense to specialize `std::decay` for `class array_ref` to be `array`?

```
namespace std{
template<> class decay<arra_ref>{typedef array type;};
}
```

What other alternatives do I have to tell generic programs that `array` is the "value type" of `array_ref`?

Is `std::decay` used in any STL algorithm?

Comment: No. Decay is a very specific quirk of C arrays and functions. `auto foo = obj` is expected to decay arrays and functions to pointers and function pointers. You can't reproduce that with your `array_ref` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether standard library algorithms use it or not. What matters is what the standard says in [meta.type.synop]/1:

> The behavior of a program that adds specializations for any of the templates defined in this subclause is undefined unless otherwise specified.

Included in "this subclause" are all of the type-traits classes, including `decay`. So don't specialize it. Ever.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think there should be a *convention* to get the "value type" of other types that are references and "not value types" themselves. (see the comments in http://stackoverflow.com/a/40892183/225186)

Comment: Maybe, we need a library (or std) trait for references `[std::]reference_traits<R>::value_type` (which nice defaults like `reference_traits<T&>::value_type == T`).