"fno-elide-constructors" not working in GCC?
Should this code, compiled with -fno-elide-constructors print "cctor"?
#include<iostream>

struct non_auto
{
  non_auto()=default;
private:
  non_auto(const non_auto&)
  {std::cout << "cctor" << std::endl;}
};

non_auto foo()
{
  return non_auto{};
}

int main()
{
  auto z = foo();
}

It turns out, for all the versions of GCC I tried, it didn't print anything and effectively elided the constructor.
https://godbolt.org/z/rPTbzzza8
What am I missing? Is it that elision can happen anyway, even with this option?
UPDATE: I am using C++17, it seems that in C++14 works but it is not very interesting because I was trying this flag to reproduce the behavior of C++14 in C++17.

Which value for -std= are you passing? Have you tried -std=c++14?

@KerrekSB Since I was interested in this feature with C++17, I didn't try C++14. With C++14 the option works. https://godbolt.org/z/MxY6bKPMh . I know that the behavior changed between 14 and 17, the origin of this question was to reproduce the behavior of C++14 in 17.

@TedLyngmo, I know, I was hoping this compiler option would keep working. If you are curious, this is what I am after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469786/disallow-the-use-of-auto-for-a-given-class-c14-vs-c17-update

Yeah, sorry, I was to quick on the trigger. It's just that mandatory elision (RVO) wasn't a thing before C++17. Since C++11 it (both NRVO and RVO) was allowed.

There is no reproducing the C++14 behavior. Calling it mandatory elision in C++17 was catchy, but inaccurate. It's not that the compiler has to elide these calls, but rather that there are no calls at all, so nothing to elide even.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The things I call RVO (since C++17) are mandatory, but perhaps that's not what you commented on?

@TedLyngmo: The point (which is relevant only in certain pedantic analyses like this one) is that it’s not an optimization since it’s just part of the language semantics now.  In particular, the constructor that would have been used in C++14 might be deleted or inaccessible.

Didn't find a dupe. Most of the questions mentioning this flag were asked before 2017.

@DavisHerring Aha... I thought StoryTeller commented on my comment, which is accurate afaik.

Going by the gcc documentation:

In C++17, the compiler is required to omit these temporaries

When compiling for C++17 or later, this flag is largely ineffective as far as RVO (returning a temporary object) goes because the language mandates that the temporaries be omitted. There is nothing to copy, so there is no copy to keep around (or to elide away; there is no option anymore).
Note: In contrast, this flag does still affect NRVO (returning a variable). However, in the case of non_auto, this would have to be done in a (possibly static) member function, since the copy constructor is private.

Would it change if the object is created in a static member? sorry, I am kind of lost in the legal language.

@alfC I now see what the "member function" part was referring to (this flag affects some inlining of function calls). I didn't read the doc carefully enough. No, being a member function does not affect this.
