# Why is std::allocate_shared() allowed to use std::addressof() on an object that is not constructed yet?

Tags: c++, addressof

According to the [cppreference notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address#Notes) for `std::to_address()`, `std::addressof()` requires the object to be already constructed:

> std::to_address can be used even when `p` does not reference storage that has an object constructed in it, in which case `std::addressof(*p)` cannot be used because there is no valid object for the parameter of `std::addressof` to bind to.

But in this code in the standard library:

```cpp
// https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__memory/shared_ptr.h
template <class _Tp, class _Alloc, class... _Args, __enable_if_t<!is_array<_Tp>::value, int> = 0>
_LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI shared_ptr<_Tp> allocate_shared(const _Alloc& __a, _Args&&... __args) {
  using _ControlBlock          = __shared_ptr_emplace<_Tp, _Alloc>;
  using _ControlBlockAllocator = typename __allocator_traits_rebind<_Alloc, _ControlBlock>::type;
  __allocation_guard<_ControlBlockAllocator> __guard(__a, 1);
  ::new ((void*)std::addressof(*__guard.__get())) _ControlBlock(__a, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
  auto __control_block = __guard.__release_ptr();
  return shared_ptr<_Tp>::__create_with_control_block(
      (*__control_block).__get_elem(), std::addressof(*__control_block));
}
```

When using `placement new`, `__guard.__get()` does not reference storage that has an object constructed in it. Why can `std::addressof(*__guard.__get())` be used here? Or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [When to use addressof(x) instead of &x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820307/when-to-use-addressofx-instead-of-x)

Comment: Those notes are for `std::to_address` not `std::addressof`

Comment: The code in the standard library implementation doesn't have to abide by the standard (or be written in anything resembling C++).

Comment: @Chris I know when to use addressof(x). My question is why can libcxx use addressof as described in the question? This seems to conflict with the Notes of cppreference.

Comment: Having said that, cppreference is not impeccable and this particular note is not necessarily correct. Un-constructed objects can be used in certain limited ways. Whether this is one of those ways remains to be seen.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Is there any documentation that specifies how unconstructed objects can be used?

Comment: Yes, it is in the standard. I cannot look for the specific place now (am on the road).

Comment: Cppreference is [correct](http://eel.is/c++draft/specialized.addressof#lib:addressof), it formally requires a constructed object. Did you find the definion of `__guard.__get()`, maybe it can return something other than a pointer?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it isn't clear what exactly in the linked passage requires that the object is fully constructed.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI *"Returns: The actual address of the object or function referenced by r"* If it's not constructed, there's no object in the first place.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It returns a pointer obtained by calling `allocator_traits::allocate(a, 1)`.See https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/e4a546756c15a609be2f65d99c8b2be13ca9ddbf/libcxx/include/__memory/allocation_guard.h#L48

Comment: So not necessarily a pointer. My guess is that they're trying to support pointer-like types here. I think the correct way would be `std::to_address(__guard.__get())`, but I'm not sure if there's any practical difference.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Also from the standard: "before the lifetime of an object starts and after its lifetime ends there are significant restrictions on the use of the object" How on earth can you possibly use an object in any way whatsoever when there is no object?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI You're quoting a note, those are non-normative and apparently can be sloppy. http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-6 has a more careful wording.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, if the use of `addressof` is correct here, I really can't understand when only `std::to_address(p)` can be used instead of `std::addressof(*p)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat as if normative parts cannot be sloppy. The standard refers to "the object" casually at places where there is no object, even in the lifetime section.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI You mean that the pointer points to valid memory, and `std::addressof` does not access the object, so this call is legal？

Comment: The standard library doesn't need the call to be legal. It could work by magic for all I care. But yeah, `std::addressof` has no need to access the object, so no reason to require that it exists/valid, even though the standard seems to require that (probably just because the wording is not careful enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [P0653R2](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0653r2.html).

> Typically the expression `addressof(*p)` is used but this is not well-defined when p does not reference storage that has an object constructed in it. This means that using this expression to obtain a raw pointer for the purpose of constructing an object (e.g. via a placement new-expression or via an allocator) is incorrect.

As @n.m.couldbeanAI said, "The standard library doesn't need the call to be legal".